# Recovery HD doesn't boot

Tags: macos, recovery-hd

I just upgraded to El Cap, and now recovery HD will not boot. It goes part of the way, but gets stuck here:

[image]

I've tried to boot multiple times, but it just gets stuck there.

Resetting the NVRAM appears to work. However, I used the terminal command: `sudo nvram -c`, instead of the startup key combination.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you need to do? Several people have made simple answers, but it's not clear if you are looking to "remake" the Recovery HD, work an alternate way to change SIP, or what "success" looks like. Worst case, choose an Apple Support article you are following and explain what step fails you or what you're not achieving...

Comment: @bmike this question has already been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got it fixed by the help of Apple Support following this Apple support page: [How to Reset NVRAM on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)

> Resetting NVRAM
>
> 1. Shut down your Mac.
> 2. Locate the following keys on the keyboard: Command (⌘), Option, P, and R.
> 3. Turn on your Mac.
> 4. Press and hold the Command-Option-P-R keys immediately after you hear the startup sound.
> 5. Hold these keys until the computer restarts and you hear the startup sound for a second time.
> 6. Release the keys.
>
> After resetting NVRAM, you may need to reconfigure settings for
>   speaker volume, screen resolution, startup disk selection, and time
>   zone information.